# BaseHTTPRequestHandler: how to return JSON from post request

Tags: python, json, post, basehttpserver

I'm new in API creation and cannot create correct server code to return JSON data from POST request. I have a Python class that inherits `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and implements the method `do_POST`.

```
import json
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import requests

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        json_data = json.loads(post_data)
        
        response_data = {
            "message": "Received POST request",
            "data": json_data
        }

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_response(2)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response_data).encode(encoding='utf_8'))

def run_server():
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8000
    server = HTTPServer((host, port), RequestHandler)
    print(f"Server running on {host}:{port}")
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Here is my request:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8000', json = {'key': 'value'})
```

Server returns status 200, but without JSON.

Comment: You have to do `response.json()` to view the json output from requests. This assumes that `response` variable contains the result of `requests.post('http://localhost:8000', json = {'key': 'value'})
`

Comment: below error appears: requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 63 (char 62)

Comment: Try printing `response.text`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just for mmy interest: is there any way to return json together with request? Or BaseHTTPRequestHandler class has not such option?